# Why I cannot detect whether the http body comes as Base64 encoded despite doing it so?

Tags: node.js, http, base64

I made a simplke add that detects whether http body is base64 endoded:

```
const connect = require('connect');

const base64RegExp = /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})$/;
const isBase64 = (str) => base64RegExp.test(str)


const app = connect();


app.use(function(req,res,next){
     
    var body = [];

    req.on('data',(data) =>
    {
        console.log('Getting Body');
        body.push(data)
    });

    req.on('end',() => {
        body = body.toString();
        res.setHeader("Content-Type",'text/plain');
        res.writeHead(200);

        if(isBase64(body)){
            res.end("BOdy base64 encoded\n");
        } else {
            res.end("BOdy not base64 encoded\n");
        }
      
    });
});

app.listen(8090);
```

But once I do:

```
base64 ~/Εικόνες/IMG_20230124_114954.jpg | curl --request POST --data @-  http://127.0.0.1:8090
```

I get:

```
BOdy not base64 encoded
```

Meaning that the app, fails to recognize a base64 encoded string as base64 enbcoded string. Any idea why fails to do so?

I tried to use the approach mentioned upon this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75916716/4706711)

### Approach 1

Furthermore I tried to use:

```
  if(isBase64(body.replace("\n","").replace("\r",""))){
    res.end("BOdy base64 encoded\n");
  } else {
    res.end("BOdy not base64 encoded\n");
  }
```

Still I get same result.

### approach 2:

I also tried this to fix it:

```
const connect = require('connect');

// const base64RegExp = /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})$/;
const isBase64 = (str) => Buffer.from(str.replace("\n","").replace("\r",""), 'base64').toString('base64') === str

const app = connect();


app.use(function(req,res,next){
     
    var body = [];

    req.on('data',(data) =>
    {
        console.log('Getting Body');
        body.push(data)
    });

    req.on('end',() => {
        body = body.toString();
        res.setHeader("Content-Type",'text/plain');
        res.writeHead(200);

        if(isBase64(body.replace("\n","").replace("\r",""))){
            res.end("BOdy base64 encoded\n");
        } else {
            res.end("BOdy not base64 encoded\n");
        }
      
    });
});

app.listen(8090);
```

Same result despite sending base64 encoded data

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just parse the string and see if it errors? Also weird to use base64 encoding for something like this but alas.

Comment: Is your regex considering newlines?

Comment: I need in order to make a reverse Http proxy @Evert for aiding me development upon http. Therefore, I need to check whether string is base64 or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl` sent the data as a URL-encoded form by default. The `+` characters in the Base64-encoded string were being interpreted as spaces, causing the regular expression test to fail. You needed to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/octet-stream` :

```
base64 ~/Εικόνες/IMG_20230124_114954.jpg | \
curl --request POST \
--data-binary @- \
--header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
http://127.0.0.1:8090
```

Data received by the server could be split into chunks, which caused the regular expression test to fail. You needed to concatenate the chunks of data before converting them to a string and testing against regex :

```js
req.on('end', () => {
  body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
  // 
});
```

Additionally, you can make your isBase64 function more robust by stripping out newlines, carriage returns, and spaces:

```js
const isBase64 = (str) => {
  const cleanedStr = str.replace(/[\n\r\s]+/g, '');
  return base64RegExp.test(cleanedStr);
};
```

Full code :

```js
const connect = require('connect');

const base64RegExp = /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})$/;

const isBase64 = (str) => {
  const cleanedStr = str.replace(/[\n\r\s]+/g, '');
  return base64RegExp.test(cleanedStr);
};

const app = connect();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  let body = [];

  req.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('Getting Body');
    body.push(data);
  });

  req.on('end', () => {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.writeHead(200);

    if (isBase64(body)) {
        console.log(body);
      res.end('Body base64 encoded\n');
    } else {
      res.end('Body not base64 encoded\n');
    }
  });
});

app.listen(8090);
```